# can not print, CUPS Service Stopped

Tags: printing

I have tried to add a printer (Ubuntu 12.04) and when clicking the printer icon, I get a dialog box yet "add printer" is grayed out can not click it.Did some research went into terminal typed in "sudo system-config-printer" that got me a new dialog box, tried to "trubleshoot' and it came back with this "CUPS Service Stopped

The CUPS print spooler does not appear to be running,. To correct this, choose System->Administration->Services from the main menu and look for the “cups” service." I tried, I looked to find the above yet got nowhere.Never thought that printing would be so difficult. ANyone have an idea why I can't add one printer, or even attempt?

Comment: I'm not using 12.04 but try this guide for 12.04: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/cups.html